# /ReportServlet.java:[25,52] error: package com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json does not exist

Tags: json, google-app-engine

I am trying to update my project- appengine.target.version to 1.9.59 in pom file. 
After I did it I get :

```
"error: package com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json does not exist"
```

I have in my code:

```
import com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject;
```

how can I Fix it?

thanks,

Gal

Comment: Could you tell if you are using Java 7 or Java 8? What version of SDK were you using before?

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8 App Engine Labs are not supported any more:

> [appengine-labs-api.jar APIs are not supported resulting in Appstats for Java not being supported.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes#june_28_2017)

[This documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8#migrating_from_unsupported_services) offers a solution:

> Migrate to [Stackdriver Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/). The SDK generates an error for apps using the com.google.appengine.tools.AppstatsFilter class in the Java 8 runtime. Make sure you delete all references to AppstatsFilter from your web.xml.